# Secure JBoss EAP 6 JMX channel

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

I'd like to know if it's possible to secure access to the JMX channel when running JBoss EAP 6 (or WildFly). AFAIK, the only available check is username and password which can be added just for remote connections. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The packaging of JMX has been removed from JBoss EAP due to probable security vulnerabilities, JMX was part of JBoss in their AS versions. I assume that you have deployed the JMX yourself onto your JBoss EAP server. So, definately, you will not get anything from JBoss EAP to secure your JMX access. But yes, you  can implement your own username and passwrod authenticaiton.

Hope this helps.